# Invalid assignment on text field

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a settings form in Flutter to store two integers but struggling a bit.

I keep getting the following message.

`The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.`

It specifically relates to this line

`onSaved: (val) => _metabolicRate = int.parse(val),`

```
class _MetabolixSettingsState extends State<MetabolixSettings> {
  int _metabolicRate = 0;

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
              child: TextFormField(
                onSaved: (val) => _metabolicRate = int.parse(val),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Enter your metabolic rate.',
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Enter your FATMAX heart rate.',
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                ],
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter some text';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Validate returns true if the
                // form is valid, or false otherwise.
                _formKey.currentState!.save();
                if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  // If the form is valid, display a snackbar. In the real world,
                  // you'd often call a server or save the information in a database.
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Saving Settings')));
                  _formKey.currentState!.save();
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
                }
                FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
                currentFocus.unfocus();
              },
              child: Text('Save'),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because val may be null value but you cannot assign a null value to parse() Try Adding "!" as below

```
onSaved: (val) => _metabolicRate = int.parse(val!),
```

Answer (score 0):

`val` is a nullable (`String?`) variable. Perform a null check before calling `parse`.

```dart
onSaved: (val) {
  if (val != null) {
    _metabolicRate = int.parse(val);
  }
},
```